# Error connection reset on android 10 device

Tags: android, session, iis, networking, connection-reset

Issue Description:

Right now on android tablet that we are using is pointing to one of our  production URL . And the connectivity is through  SIM card(private SIM card).Everything will work for a span of time and if the tablet is IDLE for sometime we are getting ERROR_CONNECTIONN_RESET and this persist for long time and when we are trying to access from other tablet [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1sW0.png)same URL its working as normal .we contacted SIM card provider  for troubleshooting and they confirmed its not from there side. Anyone faced this issue before ?

The only way we can resolve this issue is we need to deactivate and activate the SIM card again manually from SIM card provider console.

The backend server is IIS version is 10.0

Tried on multiple android device its same issue .is coming

Comment: *"Tried on multiple android device its same issue .is coming"* Sounds like it's a problem with the SIM card, then.

Comment: @Ryan switching from 4G to 3G and back to 4G then turn on/off flight mode is resolving issue automatically